# android get date return type

Tags: android, date, types, return

What is the return type of the following code,

```
 android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm", new java.util.Date());
```

I'm using this but I'm not sure what is the type of the return object by this method. I tried Date but it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html says it's `final static CharSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that just be a string formatted to `"MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm"`?